# Why does my cat become extremely well behaved when we put on his harness?

Tags: cats, behavior

We use a harness to make sure our cat doesn’t jump off the balcony when we let him out there.

We’ve noticed that the harness dramatically changes his behavior for the better. Zero biting, zero meowing, etc.

We’re just curious why this is the case, and whether it’s actually because he’s scared, anxious and we should stop. He doesn’t seem to be, but it seems too good to be true!

Thanks.

Comment: Does your cat usually bite and meow a lot? Does he still move a lot with the harness? Do his eyes get very big or do his ears turn back when he is wearing it?

Answer (score 2):

Often, a cat will freeze when putting on a harness because it triggers a survival response that they would act upon if held by a predator. It is best to make him feel comfortable through positive reinforcement. Try to give him a treat whenever he takes a step forward with the harness on, and tell him he he did a great job. This will help him feel more relaxed and comfortable, and he will get used to the harness.